# Unit testing and asserting internals of a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, caching

I am trying to test a method with unit testing, however to also make sure internally it was executed in an expected way. Here is the method simplified; It returns a value from a database but also saves it to the cache, so if it's requested again within 5 seconds, the value will be retrieved from the cache and not the DB.

```
public static string GetValue()
{
    var cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
    string value = (string)cache["test"];

    // if value is null then it was never in cache or it expired.
    if (value == null)
    {
        // Imagine here complex code that retrieves and sets "value"
        value = "OK";

        // Add it to cache to retrieve it faster if requested again within 5 sec.
        cache.Add("test", value, null, DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);

        Debug.WriteLine("From DB");
    }
    else
    {
        // Value was in cache, so it's ready to return
        Debug.WriteLine("From Cache");
    }

    return value;
}
```

This basically returns the value "OK" from a hypothetical database. However, because it uses absolute expiration of HttpRuntime.Cache, if the value is requested again within 5 seconds, it's returned from the Cache and not from the DB.

Now my question is, how to write a TestMethod that not only verifies that it returns OK, but also it the caching logic is working correctly.

Notice that depending on whether it used the DB or the Cache to get the value, a corresponding debug line is added to debug output.

So the testing method should like something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetValue_OK()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(Helpers.GetValue() == "OK");

    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    Assert.IsTrue(Helpers.GetValue() == "OK");

    // Assert that it wrote "From Cache"
    Assert.IsTrue(LastDebugLine().Contains("Cache"));

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Assert.IsTrue(Helpers.GetValue() == "OK");

    // Assert that it wrote "From DB", because theoretically over 5 seconds passed
    // So it has expired and the routine loaded it again from the DB.
    Assert.IsTrue(LastDebugLine().Contains("DB"));
}

string LastDebugLine()
{
    // Imagine a string named LastDebugOutput that contains the 
    // last line of output from Debug.WriteLine
    // The code below retrieves somehow this line.
    return String.Empty;
}
```

In the testmethod, I not only verify the correct output but also whether it was retrieved from the cache or the DB. I run the method 3 times, inserting delays between each retrieval. I want to also test if the value will be retrieved from the DB or the Cache.

The way I thought this could happen was with a method I call LastDebugLine() that retrieves the last debug info from the tested method. By reading it's status the test method knows the internals of the method so it can compare with the expected result.

Now my question has two parts:

1) What is the correct way to test all of this? Is my idea of using the debug output and checking it in the unit test correct? I could be very wrong here about the general concept so maybe this can be done a better way.

2) If however my concept is correct, what exactly should be the code in LastDebugLine() to get the last line from Debug.WriteLine?

Even if I am correct, there is still a problem as unit tests might run multithreaded, so reading the debug output like this might bring up unexpected results.

How to test this method correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. To do the whole thing as an integration test you could

- create a test which calls the method to put the value in the DB/Cache.
- then I would have the test delete the value from the db
- then call the method again.

If the value is got from the cache then you'll get the right value. if the method calls the db the test will fail.

As an alternative you could isolate the components which access the db and the cache and inject the objects which do this into your class under test. You could then provide mocks in your tests to assert that the objects are called in the right order.

It will be difficult in your current situation as you have a static method and so injecting the dependency is hard, but if you change your GetValue method so that is not static, you can pass some object that wraps your HttpRuntime.Cache and implements a similar interface, then pass a mock of that object and validate that when the object doesn't exist in the cache the other code is called and when it does exist in the cache it isn't called

If you can't change your model so that GetValue can't be static then you could look at using the MS Fakes framework or one of the other commercial products which can mock static methods.